# JQuery Ajax Post Data for odata web api

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I created a odata web api using below link 
[Microsoft Doc OData V4 Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

So my solution contains two project

1. ODATAWebApi
2. WebApp

Please find the code WebApp Code 
I am able to consume & post the data to odata web api by below code

> index.html

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" value="" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtPrice" value="" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtCategory" value="" />
<br />

<input type="button" id="btnPostData" value="Post Data Via Query " />

<input type="button" id="btnPostData2" value="Post Data Via Json Object" />
```

> Ajax Code

```
$("#btnPostData").bind("click", function () {
        var Name = $("#txtName").val();
        var Price = $("#txtPrice").val();
        var Category = $("#txtCategory").val();

    //I am creating a query string to post the data to odata web api
        var PostData = "Name=" + Name + "&Price=" + Price + "&Category=" + Category;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://localhost:44340/api/Products',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:PostData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Data: ' + data);
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
                alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });
    });
```

Using the above methodology we were able to post the data to odata web api but i want to post the data via json object as shown below but it is not working

> Product Model

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

> Json Product Model

```
$("#btnPostData2").bind("click", function () {     
        var Product = {
            Id : null,
            Name: $("#txtName").val(),
            Price: $("#txtPrice").val(),
            Category: $("#txtCategory").val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://localhost:44340/api/Products',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(Product),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Data: ' + data);
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
                alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });
    });
```

Using above methodology I am not able to post the data to odata web api.
please help or please let me known any other way to post the data to odata web api.

Answer (score 0):

`dataType` refers to what you expect as the server's response, in case the server sets no `Content-Type` header. You typically never need to use this parameter at all.

`contentType` refers to what *you* send to the server, this is what you need to set.

```
$("#btnPostData").bind("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:44340/api/Products',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Id: null,
            Name: $("#txtName").val(),
            Price: $("#txtPrice").val(),
            Category: $("#txtCategory").val()
        })
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert('Data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }).fail(function (request, error) {
        console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
    });
});
```

Unless you explicitly specify that you are sending JSON, your data will be marked as content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which will throw the server off when JSON is expected.